# What to consider when finding a good editor for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, testing, editor

Which features should I consider when finding a good editor for Javascript?

Are there any standard set of features the major development companies expect from an editor when fielded for programmers use?

Comment: That depends on the company. go for any open source project. now a days you can code the js in the browser itself.

Comment: I like the idea of coding in the browser. But it lacks features such as code navigation and intellisense. Also debugging the server side files can be problematic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Probably the first thing you need to consider is if the editor you are going to choose supports the plugins that bring the syntax highlighting, code navigation and code insight of your favorite Javascript framework.
2. It would be nice to have offered Javascript, CSS and HTML helpers by the editor.
3. Probably you should look for the ability of the editor to offer integrated Javascript debugging by hooking itself to your favorite browser's dev-tools.
4. Some editors offer plugins which can debug your server side code. This is a huge plus.
5. You should look for the editors which supports subversion in-house. This makes your life lot easier.
6. Finally, the editor should be light enough to perform fast with all these features.